# How to get address of point (x, y) in a grid sized (w, h)

Tags: arrays, grid, geometry, coordinates

[concrete example http://img246.imageshack.us/img246/602/6x7gridsm.png](http://img246.imageshack.us/img246/602/6x7gridsm.png)

By address I mean the location if you were counting left to right, top to bottom, starting with 0

I know how to get the address given point (x, y) in a grid sized (w, h)

```
  address = (y * w) + x
```

That is, in a grid 7 x 6 units, the point (2, 5) gives address 37 (*see illustration above*)

How do I get point (x,y), given address 37 and grid (7, 6)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your description, it looks like you are doing column first addressing.  In this case, you can find x by calculating (address%w).  Once you have x, you can get y by calculating (address-x)/w.

Comment: `y` is just `address / w` without any further work if indexing is zero-based and division is integer.

Answer (score 2):

```
x=Address MOD w
y=Address INT_DIV w
```

Answer (score 1):

```
x = address mod w<br>
y = address div w
```